# Looking for a trance gate midi device for Ableton Live/Max for Live

Tags: software, midi, electronic-music, ableton-live

I am looking for a midi effect for Max for Live which allows the creation of arbitrary trance patterns. Something like the one embedded in FM8, just to be clear. Many people implement trancegates on the audio output of some synth. This is not what I am interested in. I need something that is operating on the midi level.

Example: in case of some long notes used in a chord, I would like to having that chord being triggered with a certain pre-defined pattern that might have a short length, for example a bar or half bar.

Note that this means that the chord should *not* be arpeggiated, all notes should be played at the same time, as chords.

I think that this is a device that might be very commonly desired in many projects so it has to be already built by someone.
I tried a few devices for max for life but my experience with those was unsatisfactory.

Here you can see FM8's arpeggiator, which has "all notes" capability:

[image: FM8's arpeggiator]

As you can see all the input notes that are active can be played simultaneously with selecting the "All" option under each entry of the pattern.

**Why can't I just put the rythmic structure in the piano roll?**

I need to be able to quickly change, independently, chords and rhythmic pattern. It's clear why it's so important when considering a track with a very long and articulated chord progression. 
If I have to put a certain rhythmic structure in the piano roll from the beginning, then I am unable to quickly experiment with different rhythmic structures after that a chord progression has been decided.

Any pointers? Hints?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What difference would that device have with using the piano roll? And why can't you use the piano roll for this?

Comment: Because I need to be able to quickly change, independently, chords and rhythmic pattern. You can visualize why it's so important if you consider a track with a very long and articulated chord progression. If I have to put a certain rhythmic structure in the piano roll from the beginning, then I am unable to experiment with different ones (or, yes, I can, but at a huge cost)

Comment: I'm sure you have looked into it, but the built in Ableton MIDI Effects can be pretty powerful. The Midi Apreggiator can be used to repeat notes without really arpeggiating and there's also the note length effect.

Comment: @Charles, yes, I have looked into Midi arpeggiator. It does not allow for arbitrary patterns

Answer (score 2):

Use CC11 (expression) clip automation (envelope view)

Answer (score 0):

There's A BUNCH. I used to mess around with Storm Gate 3, but here's a list!

KVR Search: Gate
http://www.kvraudio.com/q.php?search=1&q=gate

Comment: Did you even read my question? I asked for a gate that operates at MIDI level, *not* AUDIO level.

Comment: Kirnu may be your best bet **

http://www.kirnuarp.com/

It's an arp, but can be programmed like a gate